# how do i export all keys to csv file redis-cli?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am looking to export everything in Redis to a file using redis-cli

I understand

```
redis-cli -h XXXX --csv get keyname[****] > filename.csv
```

will export the one given key to a file, but how do I get every single key/value that exists into a file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that, but with some coding, you can achieve that. In your preferred programming language, you can implement the following logic:

1. [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) the database to obtain key names
2. For each key name obtained, issue a [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) call to get its value type.
3. Per value type, do the equivalent read command (e.g. `GET` for strings, `HGETALL` for hashes...) and manipulate the reply to CSV format.